# Cost per Sharepoint Group created

Tags: groups

Does it cost extra after the licensing fee to create different groups in Sharepoint? If so how much?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no cost for a SharePoint Group or additional groups. These are licensed via your SharePoint licensing already in place.